# Images not Lazy Loading and Caching

Tags: android, image, file, listview, caching

I am making an android app in which I am trying to lazyload and cache the images in a listview. I got the code from [here](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/). The example from this [Github](https://github.com/cacois/TweetView) project works perfectly fine for me, but when i try to use the same example in my app it dosnt work. This is my ImageManager class.

```
public class ImageManager {

    private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> imageMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

    private File cacheDir;
    private ImageQueue imageQueue = new ImageQueue();
    private Thread imageLoaderThread = new Thread(new ImageQueueManager());

    public ImageManager(Context context) {
        // Make background thread low priority, to avoid affecting UI
        // performance
        imageLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);

        // Find the dir to save cached images
        String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            cacheDir = new File(sdDir, "data/floapp");
            System.out
                    .println("coming here in mounted media and created folder floapp");
        } else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        if (imageMap.containsKey(url)) {

            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageMap.get(url).get());
        } else {
            queueImage(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    }

    private void queueImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        // This ImageView might have been used for other images, so we clear
        // the queue of old tasks before starting.
        imageQueue.Clean(imageView);
        ImageRef p = new ImageRef(url, imageView);
        synchronized (imageQueue.imageRefs) {
            imageQueue.imageRefs.push(p);
            imageQueue.imageRefs.notifyAll();
        }

        // Start thread if it's not started yet
        if (imageLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            imageLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        System.out.println("coming in getbitmap");
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        System.out.println("cachedir=" + cacheDir.getPath());
        System.out.println("filename=" + filename);

        // Is the bitmap in our cache?
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
        System.out.println("bitmap after decoding the file thingy file path="
                + f.getPath());
        if (bitmap != null)
            return bitmap;

        // Nope, have to download it
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
            // save bitmap to cache for later
            writeFile(bitmap, f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    /** Classes **/

    private class ImageRef {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageRef(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    // stores list of images to download
    private class ImageQueue {
        private Stack<ImageRef> imageRefs = new Stack<ImageRef>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView view) {

            for (int i = 0; i < imageRefs.size();) {
                if (imageRefs.get(i).imageView == view)
                    imageRefs.remove(i);
                else
                    ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImageQueueManager implements Runnable {
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // Thread waits until there are images in the
                    // queue to be retrieved
                    if (imageQueue.imageRefs.size() == 0) {
                        synchronized (imageQueue.imageRefs) {
                            imageQueue.imageRefs.wait();
                        }
                    }

                    // When we have images to be loaded
                    if (imageQueue.imageRefs.size() != 0) {
                        ImageRef imageToLoad;

                        synchronized (imageQueue.imageRefs) {
                            imageToLoad = imageQueue.imageRefs.pop();
                        }

                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(imageToLoad.url);
                        imageMap.put(imageToLoad.url,
                                new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bmp));
                        Object tag = imageToLoad.imageView.getTag();

                        // Make sure we have the right view - thread safety
                        // defender
                        if (tag != null
                                && ((String) tag).equals(imageToLoad.url)) {
                            BitmapDisplayer bmpDisplayer = new BitmapDisplayer(
                                    bmp, imageToLoad.imageView);

                            Activity a = (Activity) imageToLoad.imageView
                                    .getContext();

                            a.runOnUiThread(bmpDisplayer);
                        }
                    }

                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    private class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i) {
            bitmap = b;
            imageView = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get FileNotFoundException, but the files are being created in the folder on my sdcard. can anyone please help me??
-Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I guess it has something to do with the url. I got a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218807/android-filenotfound-exception-cannot-getinputstream-from-image-url-that-does). My urls are like these "http://graph.facebook.com/1519317701/picture"

Comment: where throw `FileNotFoundException`, `cacheDir = new File(sdDir, "data/floapp");` here or where?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should have mentioned it earlier. The error is at Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

Comment: The print statements work perfectly fine. The output of the cachedir is
cachedir=/mnt/sdcard/data/floapp

Comment: if it's in `decodeFile`, you can output the path and check it, maybe the path is not existed.

Comment: I am printing the file path and it prints it correctly as expected. It prints
'bitmap after decoding the file thingy file path=/mnt/sdcard/data/floapp/-2088703618'

Comment: as you said, you check the file is is existed, it hard to understand

Comment: That is why I asked this question on StackOverflow, otherwise I wouldnt have asked it :P I cant figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to try this example for once:

1. [Lazy list with images by Fedor](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
2. [Universal Image loader for ListView, Gallery, GridView.](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am using the first link 'Lazy list with images by fedor' and in the ImageLoader class, decodeFile(), i am printing the file f.getpath() and its printing correctly as "/mnt/sdcard/LazyList/1534745000" and in the BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o); am getting an exception as "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/LazyList/1534745000 (No such file or directory)".

Comment: I guess its the same problem, the code is fine, its just that its not able to decodestream from it. I dont know the reason why :( I have already wasted a lot of time on this...Please help.

Comment: Please see my updated question and throw some light if you can!

Comment: My problem has still not been solved, but i tried the above first link and it worked for me.

Comment: Universal image loader is i think the best solution, because it works for ListView, Gallery, GridView.....

Answer (score 2):

Another good solution is ImageLoader (http://androidimageloader.com). This provides async image loading and transparent two-level caching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess here... I had the same issue, and I fixed it by adding the "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission to my application manifest. Though you might have added it already...