# FileNotFoundException on Android version > 2.3

Tags: java, android, inputstream, filenotfoundexception

I try to download a file to sdcard on my phone. On Android 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 everything works like intended, but on Android 4.0 (testen on emulator and my Galaxy Nexus) it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Stacktrace:

```
02-27 21:49:06.733: W/System.err(27648): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.wdr.de/wdrlive/media/wdr5.m3u
02-27 21:49:06.733: W/System.err(27648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
02-27 21:49:06.733: W/System.err(27648):    at de.arvidg.test.StartActivity$9.run(StartActivity.java:833)
02-27 21:49:06.733: W/System.err(27648):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My method for downloading file:

```
downloadFile("http://www.wdr.de/wdrlive/media/wdr5.m3u");

    public void downloadFile(final String fileUrl) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);

                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                    urlConnection.connect();

//                  File cacheDir = appContext.getExternalCacheDir();
//                  File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard", "/cacheFile.ext");
                    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/cacheFile.ext");

                    if(!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                    int downloadedSize = 0;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bufferLength = 0;

                    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                        Log.d(TAG, "downloadedSize = " + downloadedSize + " | totalSize = " + totalSize);
//                      updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

                    }
                    fileOutput.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: It's not what's causing your problem, but you should not be using an absolute file name for the cache file. Try this instead: `File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"cacheFile.ext");` (note the absence of "/").

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will do it for sure. Anyone get idea where the error comes from?

Comment: Check the response code urlConnection.getResponseCode(); before process input stream.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. 405 - Method not allowed. Is there another download message ("GET" dont seems to work).

Comment: Try to comment this string urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); in your code.

Comment: Yury: The same error. `urlConnection.getRequestMethod()` returns only `POST`. I think I have to live, that I cant get the file. Is it possible to open file and get content?

Comment: The weird thing is, that it work on Android 2.2. :D

Comment: Some one suggest using apache httpClient can fix it,not sure if it works in your case here ICS, worth to [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218807/android-filenotfound-exception-cannot-getinputstream-from-image-url-that-does)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simple remove `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`

Thanks to pfn @ #android-dev

Comment: Nice answer +1 for short and convenient Thanks it solved my problem.

Comment: Good it is working. but with localhost IP not by using 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Apparently this line in JAVA forces the http protocol to change a GET to a POST regardless of specifying the GET

Comment: But that gives me an error

 IO error: Does not support output

 java.net.Protocol Exception: Does not support output

Comment: same here System.err(9083): java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: GET

Answer (score 8):

So to answer the original question, a `FileNotFoundException` also comes when you get an error message from the server and then try to access `getInputStream()`. If the Response code is a 400 or above, any call to `getInputStream()` will throw this error. In this case, you should check `getErrorStream()` instead. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991347/java-eofexception-when-getinputstream-from-post/18151239#18151239).