# BitmapFactory decode issue

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

```
url="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/946xvariable_height/public/ladee_spin_2_in_motion_0_0.jpg?itok=yNhf69rE";

 try { 
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                input.close();
                return bitmap;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                return null;
            }
```

I was tryning to retreive image from the url but no matter what it always returns null. In debugging mode I have observed that it happens when it tries input.close();  . 
How can I possibly get the Image.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proper way to load Bitmap:

```
    InputStream is;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(DRAW_SOURCE);


    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

However, as I see you close stream before finish to decoding it.

If so, use other way:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input, 8192);

ByteArrayBuffer buff = new ByteArrayBuffer(64);
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
    buff.append((byte)current);
 }

  byte[] imageData = buff.toByteArray();
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);

  try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

BTW, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218807/android-filenotfound-exception-cannot-getinputstream-from-image-url-that-does), it should work also